# Adding UIImageView to ARSCNView scene background causes Saturation/Hue to be off

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, arscnview

```
@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  let imageView = UIImageView(frame: sceneView.bounds)
  imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
  imageView.image = UIImage(named: "myImage")
  sceneView.scene.background.contents = imageView
}
```

This causes the image to look like this:

[image]

The original image:

[image]

I don't want that red tint. How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: The color of the image is changed. it has a red tint when I try to use UIImageView.

Comment: that's still not a question. Please edit a question into the post.

Comment: Updated: I don't want that red tint. How do I prevent that from happening?